# How do I stop the alarm when the button is pressed?

Tags: android

I understand that the question is most likely elementary, but I can not think of it myself. 
I make a simple alarm clock, but I can not figure out how to make an alarm clock at the click of a `button`. 
Here is the class with Broadcast:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
   Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM); 
   Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(),notification); 
   ringtone.play();
```

And the button is in the main class.

Comment: okay you want to stop your ringing alarm while user press a button which is defined by you.
am i right ?

Comment: Yes, I want press a button and stop rington

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. define a interface in your Utility class.
2. implement this interface inside your Receiver.
3. stop alarm via calling method of interface.

private interface RingtoneHelper {
        void stopRingtone();
    }

    class Utility {

        public static RingtoneHelper ringtoneHelper;


    }

    public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            final Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(),notification);
            ringtone.play();

            Utility.ringtoneHelper = new RingtoneHelper() {
                @Override
                public void stopRingtone() {
                    if(ringtone.isPlaying()) {
                        ringtone.stop();
                    }
                }
            };

        }
    }

// todo add click action for your button
if(Utility.ringtoneHelper != null) {
Utility.ringtoneHelper.stopRingtone();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! And you can slightly more? I can not register a button here from another class (((

Comment: just put this code inside your button onClickListener
if(Utility.ringtoneHelper != null) {
Utility.ringtoneHelper.stopRingtone();
}